# Installed @types definition not being picked up by TS compiler

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I am working on a project that has been using typings and I now need to install a definition from the @types repository.

I have already installed the @type and see it in my node_modules\@types folder but my TS compiler is not picking up the types.

Our tsconfig.json is as follows:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "rootDir": "../",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noImplicitThis": false,
        "noUnusedLocals": false,
        "noUnusedParameters": false,
        "pretty": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "allowUnreachableCode": false,
        "declaration": false,
        "allowJs": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "typeRoots" : ["./typings/index.d.ts", "../../node_modules/@types"],
    },
    "include": [
        "./typings/index.d.ts",
        "./app/**/*.module.ts",
        "./app/**/*.run.ts",
        "./app/**/*.routes.ts",
        "./app/**/*.enum.ts",
        "./app/**/*.controller.ts",
        "./app/**/*.model.ts",
        "./app/**/*.directive.ts",
        "./app/**/*.component.ts",
        "./app/**/*.filter.ts",
        "./app/**/*.service.ts",
        "./app/interfaces/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "dist",
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Note that our tsconfig does not live at the root of our project but in a sub-directory as follows
[image]

I added an extra path to the typeRoots to point at my node_modules directory for the project, but this has made no difference.

The particular library I have installed the @types for is leaflet, and the opening line for their index.d.ts is:

```
export as namespace L;
```

When I'm keying in 'L' in one of my TS source files, the compiler is not finding this.

I must be doing something wrong, is it possible to use a mix of types from the typings and @types repositories?

Ultimately we should be moving over to just using @types, but I want to figure out why I can't get this particular leaflet @type being detected in my editor (I am using VS Code in case thats relevant)

Answer (score 0):

> By default all visible “@types” packages are included in your compilation. Packages in node_modules/@types of any enclosing folder are considered visible; specifically, that means packages within ./node_modules/@types/, ../node_modules/@types/, ../../node_modules/@types/, and so on.
>
> If typeRoots is specified, only packages under typeRoots will be included. For example:

So step one would be to remove you `typeRoots` and see if the Leaflet types get picked up (you may get an error for your `typings/index.d.ts` at this stage.

If Leaflet works (fingers crossed it does), then you need to check your path back to `node_modules` here...

```
"typeRoots" : ["./typings/index.d.ts", "../../node_modules/@types"],
```

In particular, I wonder if these paths are affected by the `rootDir` configuration in your file?

Comment: Thanks @Fenton, With my current config, I have realised I am actually able to pick up interfaces and classes that are being exported from the leaflet index.d.ts file, they are just not being wrapped in the 'L' namespace defined on the first line of the file.

Comment: Are you expecting it to be a global `L`, or are you importing `L` from Leaflet?

Comment: Well I was hoping I could access it globally, I did try adding an `import * as L from "leaflet"` in my TS file where I want use the types, but this didnt help me. I am probably misunderstanding how to use @types, or maybe have something misconfigured in my tsconfig? I have raised a separate question on being unable to access exported namespaces [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552150/unable-to-access-global-l-namespace-after-installing-types-leaflet)