# Unable to access global L namespace after installing @types/leaflet

Tags: typescript, leaflet, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I am struggling to get a reference to an exported namespace for the [leaflet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/leaflet) type definitions in my TypeScript project.

After installing the types using `npm install --save @types/leaflet` my TS compiler (I am using VS Code) is able to find some of the exported classes and interfaces in the type definition file, e.g. Transformation, Class, but I am unable to access any of the namespaces exported.

I need to be able to reference the `L` global so I can make calls to the leaflet API, but the compiler is not picking this up for me.

I did try using an import statement in my TS file I am trying to use leaflet in, e.g.

```
import * as L from 'leaflet'
```

But again, I can still only access the classes\interfaces this time on my imported alias, e.g. `L.Transformation`

I cannot initialise a new map, e.g by using `L.map(...)` since `L` is not accessible for me - [map](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/leaflet/index.d.ts#L1385) is an exported function in the type definition file

So I am unsure how to reference and use the `L` global for leaflet in my project.

Can anyone assist please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using an older version of @types/leaflet. I have the same issue and solved it by using the 1.0.69 version.
npm install --save @types/leaflet@1.0.69

Using anything above that (1.2+) seems to lead to this error.